# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling, typeerror

I know there's plenty of questions related to this error and I've checked most of them and none help me solve my issue. (Which seems so easy to debug...)

I have an array (which is empty aat first):

```
var words = [];
```

And my function hasLetter, checks if we find a letter (object) in the array (that I call here: d) words.

```
function hasLetter(letter,d){

// if words[0] not null should return object of letter "a", here we getting
// the index of the letter (since ascii of "a" is 97, I substract 97)
var ascii = letter.charCodeAt(0)-97;

//Trying to not get an error with this but still creates an err
if(typeof d[ascii ] !== "undefined" && d[ascii ] !== null && d[ascii ].length > 0){
    if(d[ascii].letter == letter){
        return true;
    }
}
return false; }
```

and I have a function called addLetter which checks if hasLetter returns true/false and then creates or not accordingly a new node.

```
function addLetter(letter,d){
var ascii = letter.charCodeAt(0)-97;
if(!hasLetter(letter,d)){
    document.write("This letter" + letter + " hasn't been found in words.");
    d[ascii] = new Node(letter);
}
    document.write("This letter " + letter + " already exists in words.");
    document.write(d[ascii].letter);
```

}

and if I test:

```
addLetter("a",words);
```

it returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I don't know what to do to say "if it's undefined then don't look into it or something along those lines...

Thanks

Comment: If you want to find a letter in array, then (words.indexOf(letter) > 0) will return you whether the letter is present or not.

Comment: You can't do `hasLetter("a",words[]);`, should be `hasLetter("a",words);`

Comment: @mohamedrias no it won't.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Greg  thanks I wasted my 1 day to debugging and when I came here and I resolved my issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is here:

```
hasLetter("a",words[]);
```

You are passing the first item of `words`, instead of the array.

Instead, pass the array to the function:

```
hasLetter("a",words);
```

Problem solved!

---

Here's a breakdown of what the problem was:

I'm guessing in your browser (chrome throws a different error), `words[] == words[0]`, so when you call `hasLetter("a",words[]);`, you are actually calling `hasLetter("a",words[0]);`. So, in essence, you are passing the first item of words to your function, *not* the array as a whole.

Of course, because `words` is just an empty array, `words[0]` is `undefined`. Therefore, your function call is actually:

```
hasLetter("a", undefined);
```

which means that, when you try to access `d[ascii]`, you are actually trying to access `undefined[0]`, hence the error.

Comment: Yes exactly, I failed my call hasLetter by adding "[]" but my error actually came from another function (well it came from this one but upon calling another one). I shall create a new thread (or should I update this one?) but thanks for explaining this, it helped :)

Comment: OK, yeah, that makes sense; I was confused by the error you were getting, I would have expected it to be more along the lines of "Unexpected ]". Anyway, thanks! If you vote this answer up, I'll have 2k reptation!

Answer (score 3):

There is no error when I use your code,

but I am calling the `hasLetter` method like this:

```
hasLetter("a",words);
```